# Building GLSDK on Mac - platform.h not found

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I am trying to build GLSDK on mac.
I downloaded the source, did `premake4 xcode3` which created all project files for xcode.
Now I am trying to build everything, managed to build glload,glimg,glutil,glmesh just fine, I've got freeglut working from XQuartz package so I guess I don't need to build the one included with glsdk.

Problems start when I try to build glfw:

```
Wojciechs-MacBook-Air:glfw wojciechmusialkiewicz$ xcodebuild
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET glfw OF PROJECT glfw WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Debug) ===
Check dependencies

CompileC obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/enable.o lib/enable.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_LIB -D_DEBUG -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/library/include -Iinclude -Ilib -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/library -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/enable.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/enable.dia -c /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/lib/enable.c -o /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/enable.o
In file included from /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/lib/enable.c:31:
lib/internal.h:92:10: fatal error: 'platform.h' file not found
#include "platform.h"
         ^
1 error generated.

CompileC obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/glext.o lib/glext.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_LIB -D_DEBUG -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/library/include -Iinclude -Ilib -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/library -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/glext.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/glext.dia -c /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/lib/glext.c -o /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/glext.o
In file included from /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/lib/glext.c:31:
lib/internal.h:92:10: fatal error: 'platform.h' file not found
#include "platform.h"
         ^
1 error generated.

CompileC obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/image.o lib/image.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_LIB -D_DEBUG -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/library/include -Iinclude -Ilib -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/library -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/image.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/image.dia -c /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/lib/image.c -o /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/image.o
In file included from /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/lib/image.c:56:
lib/internal.h:92:10: fatal error: 'platform.h' file not found
#include "platform.h"
         ^
1 error generated.

CompileC obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fullscreen.o lib/fullscreen.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_LIB -D_DEBUG -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/glfwD-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/library/include -Iinclude -Ilib -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/library -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fullscreen.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fullscreen.dia -c /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/lib/fullscreen.c -o /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fullscreen.o
In file included from /Users/wojciechmusialkiewicz/glsdk_0.4.4/glfw/lib/fullscreen.c:31:
lib/internal.h:92:10: fatal error: 'platform.h' file not found
#include "platform.h"
         ^
1 error generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/enable.o lib/enable.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/glext.o lib/glext.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/image.o lib/image.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC obj/Debug/glfw.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fullscreen.o lib/fullscreen.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(4 failures)
```

I've tried googling what this `platform.h` file is,but there is no clear answer, not even if it's present on MacOS - I can't find it on my computer so I guess that it isn't.
Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: platform.h will be in glfw/lib/cocoa. It is GLFW that is trying to include/link against that. Remove GLFW from the premake4.lua that you are using to generate the xcode project.

Comment: there is no GLFW in the premake4.lua.

copying from glfw.xcodeproj:
"Platform specific definitions goes in platform.h (which also includes
glfw.h)"

Answer (score 3):

There is a `glfw.lua` file in the `glfw` folder. Open that up and make a configuration for "**macosx**" and then add the directory "`lib/cocoa`" to the include directories. I also defined `_GLFW_COCOA`, `_GLFW_NSGL`, and `_GLFW_USE_OPENGL`